# Changing drawableBottom with java

Tags: java, android, drawable

Is it possible to change a drawable on a button via java?

Example; I have a button like this.

```
<Button 
style="@style/Buttons" 
android:id="@+id/butFavTeam"
android:drawableBottom="@drawable/venue"/>
```

I want to change the current drawableBottom image with another from my drawable directory.

Comment: Further to the answers below, is there any way of doing this in API  < 3.0 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at this method:

```
/*
Sets the Drawables (if any) to appear to the left of, above, to the right of, and below the text. Use 0 if you do not want a Drawable there. The Drawables' bounds will be set to their intrinsic bounds.
*/
public void  setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds  (Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom)
```

Try this:

```
/*remember to first clear the callback of the drawable you are replacing to prevent memory leaks...
* Get the Drawables for the button by calling: myButton.getCompoundDrawables(), then loop through that calling myOldDrawable.setCallback(null);
* e.g:*/

for(Drawable myOldDrawable : myButton.getCompoundDrawables())
{
   myOldDrawable.setCallback(null);
}

//use null where you don't want a drawable
myButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,null, myNewDrawable);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: The NULL value is **incorrect**. Use 0 if you do not want a Drawable there .setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, myIcon); [Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: The null is correct. In his example he is passing actual Drawables, so null is the correct 'no value' for that version of the method. There is another version, which presumably you are thinking of, where you pass four drawable id values (ie. ints), and for which 0 is the correct thing to pass where you don't want a Drawable.

Comment: **Both** approaches are correct. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29 and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

Answer (score 3):

Just found it.

```
Drawable myIcon = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myVenue);
butFavTeam.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, myIcon);
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way... make sure you don't accidentally use the method setCompoundDrawables(). It takes the same parameters as setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(), but it's obviously expecting some bounds details too.

I fell prey for this because I lazily accepted the very first type-ahead method. I'm posting this in case you too cannot figure out why the images aren't displaying.